# How to define a global resource .resx file per language?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I doing localization for one site.

But I found that I need to define a new ".resx" per View or Controller.

Is there a way to set up a global file for each language instead of creating one file per (number of Localization) * views?

Answer (score 1):

From the official documentation "There's no option to use a global shared resource file.".

You can only use global resource file for DataAnnotations localization:

```
  services.AddMvc().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
        {
            options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
            {
                return factory.Create(typeof(ErrorMessage));
            };
        });
```

where ErrorMessage is just an empty class.

Comment: So how do you specify the Path/file name of your resource file?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to create a wrapper for `IStringLocalizer`. Here's what I use:

```
    public class Localizer
    {
        private readonly IStringLocalizer localizer;

        public Localizer(IStringLocalizerFactory fact)
        {
            var type = typeof(SharedResource);
            var assembly = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName).Name;
            localizer = fact.Create(nameof(SharedResource), assembly);
        }

        public LocalizedString this[string key] => localizer[key];

        public LocalizedString this[string key, params object[] arguments] => localizer[key, arguments];
    }
```

And then inject that into your controllers and views. Based on this guy's blog post: https://medium.com/@flouss/asp-net-core-localization-one-resx-to-rule-them-all-de5c07692fa4